# Get the percentage of each class in classification

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification

Let me explain my question with an example.
Imagine our machine learning model is trained using many different classes such as rectangle, circle, and triangular, etc.
Now I want to give it a new shape, for instance, a rounded corner rectangle.
What I need is not only the classification of this new shape I need to extract the similarity percentage. For example, 85% rectangle and 14% circle, and 1% other classes.
Is it a multiclass and multioutput problem? I think the multioutput problems are also a sort of binary classification. Is this a classification problem or maybe I should go through regression problems?

How can I achieve my goal for example in Scikit learn? What are the keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many model classes in Sci-Kit learn have a method called "predict_proba(X)". This is a method that can predict the probability of the predicted classification. Below is a link from the sci-kit learn documentation that shows an example of how this would work in practice.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration.html?highlight=classification